# Can anyone explain the different Perl Cache implementations?

Tags: perl, caching

There's a bunch of different Cache implementations in CPAN. I'm using Cache::File (because it is installed on my operating system) but I also see references to File::Cache, Cache:FileCache, Cache::Cache, and so on. Many appear to be implementations of "the cache interface" which appears to be either module "Cache" or "Cache::Cache".

A google search for the right documentation is difficult. Can anyone explain the different Cache implementations (with emphasis on file caching) and why there are so many?

Bonus points for telling me what I actually set out to discover: what's the syntax for the expiration time values in Cache::File? Ive only seen a few examples like *600* or *'600 sec'*, but no explanation of the full syntax.

Thanks.

*Update: I think I have found the answer to my bonus question [here](http://search.cpan.org/~cleishman/Cache-2.04/lib/Cache/Entry.pm).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This might be of some help, though it's a bit dated (2005?): [Comparison of different PERL caching modules](http://cpan.robm.fastmail.fm/cache_perf.html)
2. Also, if you read Russian, this post has VERY good summary of caching modules... I seriously doubt some automated translator (bablefish/google) would work for an article like that but have a shot at it: http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=3448
3. Also, the difference between Cache and Cache::Cache (which as you noted are two main "interfaces" in java sense) for caching modules is explained in [Cache's POD](http://search.cpan.org/~cleishman/Cache-2.04/lib/Cache.pm#DIFFERENCES_FROM_CACHE::CACHE)
4. Also, here are some modules that have actual explanations of why they specifically should be used and/or their details:

   - http://perl-cache.sourceforge.net/
   - http://blog.woobling.org/2010/07/why-another-caching-module.html

Comment: If anyone here is a russian speaker and feels like translating this page: http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=3448 - they would have undying fame and OP's gratitude :)